# How do you put a list inside of an object C#?

Tags: c#, list, object

New to C#, sorry if the wording is a little off. I want to make one of my fields in an object as a list. My below code does not let me access the list.

```
class Bag
{
    public string name;
    public int space;
    public int cost;
    List<string> items = new List<string>();


    public Bag(string name, int space, int cost, List<string> items)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.space = space;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.items = items;
    }
```

I am not able to use items when using the below code:

```
bag1.items.Add("Money");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make it `public`

```
public List<string> items = new List<string>();
```

For more information about why you need to do this, see [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

> `public`: The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the
> same assembly or another assembly that references it.

Additionally, you should prefer *properties* over *fields* for public access

```
public string name { get; set; } 
public int space { get; set; } 
public int cost { get; set; } 
public List<string> items { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much. What would the advantages of get/ set be? If it is public cant I just assign new values with bag1.name = "New Name";?

Comment: "*What would the advantages of get/ set*" - @Forrest in some ways it doesn't make a difference for extremely simple applications. However it does have some advantages, you can modify the getters and setters without making breaking changes, you can also *databind* properties you cant with fields, you are also exposing internal state of your object externally which is generally considered smelly. There are lots more pros and cons, its worth doing some research into this question (in and of itself)

Comment: How do I add strings into the list in my object? Bag small = new Bag("Small Bag", 9, 0, "Money"); doesnt work

Comment: @Forrest `bag1.items.Add("Money");` ? if you want default strings, you can initialize that in the constructor

Comment: would I set that to null in the constructor to start with an empty list?

Comment: @Forrest `new Bag("Small Bag", 9, 0, new List<string>(){"Money"});`

Comment: is there a way to create the object and leave the list completely empty to start?

Comment: @Forrest you can remove the initialization from the property `public List<string> items { get; set; }`, and also remove it from the constructor